# graphical overlay on top of mpeg stream

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video, mpeg

I`m working on some project and i want to "alter" mpeg ts / mpeg dash and add a graphical overlay on top of video. (add text on some frames).
Vide needs to be played with basic html5 player.

I can alter the video and just draw on top of it (read it frame by frame, draw with opencv and reencode).
It there any other way to achieve this ? i.e. adding additional "drawing layer" on top of video (i checked "Content labeling" Content labeling for ISO/IEC 14496-1 for mpeg ts), but not really sure whether this is supported on html5 players.

Comment: for HTML5 video you can either burn the changes you want into the mp4 source that you play, or overlay content on top of the video at playback time (which won't be part of the video if downloaded) - to do that you can use CSS to position an element over the video and load the content you need

Comment: the first one is exactly what i`m trying to avoid, draw and reencode in video,